# Error: EISDIR, illegal operation on a directory when adding platform using cordova 3.5.0

Tags: android, cordova

I have all the setting done, but when i try to add platform to the project i created i got this error. am really no idea where should i start to debug. PLease help

```
Creating android project...
Error: EISDIR, illegal operation on a directory
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:481:19)
    at Object.fs.readSync (C:\Documents and Settings\Wong Wai Hong\Application D
ata\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\tar\node_modu
les\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:218:23)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:320:28)
    at C:\Documents and Settings\Wong Wai Hong\Application Data\npm\node_modules
\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\platform.js:351:42
    at _fulfilled (C:\Documents and Settings\Wong Wai Hong\Application Data\npm\
node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Documents and Settings\Wong Wai Hong\Applic
ation Data\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)`enter code here`
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Documents and Settings\Wong Wai Hong\
Application Data\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
    at C:\Documents and Settings\Wong Wai Hong\Application Data\npm\node_modules
\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:821:14
    at flush (C:\Documents and Settings\Wong Wai Hong\Application Data\npm\node_
modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Comment: this error is because of node modules. did you try installing npm and node.js ?